# How can I find the correct name for my microphone and sound output using aplay or pacmd or something else, to apply in asound.conf?

Tags: configuration, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, mediaplayer

I need to write a default mic and default speaker output in the `asound.conf` config file. But I don't know exactly how I can find my external sound card or microphone device's name, so that on reboot or unplug/plug I don't have to reconfigure it again.

I tried to find them by using:

```
sun@sun-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/tmp$ pacmd dump | grep alsa_input
set-source-volume alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo 0xddb
set-source-mute alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo no
suspend-source alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo yes
set-source-volume alsa_input.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-mono 0x9091
set-source-mute alsa_input.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-mono no
suspend-source alsa_input.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-mono yes
set-source-volume alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_8E9E4FCF-02-C920.analog-stereo 0xfffe
set-source-mute alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_8E9E4FCF-02-C920.analog-stereo no
suspend-source alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_8E9E4FCF-02-C920.analog-stereo yes
set-default-source alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_8E9E4FCF-02-C920.analog-stereo
```

or:

```
sun@sun-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/tmp$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Device [C-Media USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

But it confused me. Which one is the name that I have to use when doing `sudo vim /etc/asound.conf`?

From the information given above this device is my microphone:

```
card 2: Device [C-Media USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And from the above information this device is my audio output:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

How can I tell this in my `/etc/asound.conf`? I tried the following but it does not work:

```
pcm.usb
{
    type hw
    card C-Media USB Audio Device
}
pcm.!default
{
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "dmix"
    }
    capture.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "usb"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want playback on your build in sondcard and capture (microphone) from external USB device.

Your external device is listed as **card 2: device 0** and your build in soundcard as **card 0: device 0**

I think your `asound.conf` should look something like this:

```
pcm.!default
{
  playback.pcm
  {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
  }

  playback.capture
  {
    type hw
    card 2
    device 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Did some Googleing and found [this](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/DeviceNames) page on alsa-project.org. Try something like `plug:default:C-Media USB Audio Device` for the USB device and `plug:default:HDA Intel PCH` for the build in device.

Comment: in that case `card` and `device` lines should be removed by adding those lines right?

Comment: @YumYumYum I think so, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: It says invalid file: sun@sun-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ alsamixer
ALSA lib conf.c:1686:(snd_config_load1) _toplevel_:24:4:Unexpected char
ALSA lib conf.c:3406:(config_file_open) /etc/asound.conf may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc) could be of some help. It talks about `asound.conf` and naming of devices.